# Why java.sql.ResultSet.getString is an Information Leakage vulnerability

Tags: java, databases

Recently I started using LAPSE+ for static code analysis and it kept on pointing `java.sql.ResultSet.getString` as an Information Leakage. The `ResultSet` is properly closed after its usage.

LAPSE+ does this only for `ResultSet.getString()` and `ResultSet.getObject()`. For example, `ResultSet.getDate()` is not taken as a vulnerability. This behavior confirms to [this OWASP page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Searching_for_Code_in_J2EE/Java), which indicates only those two getters in `ResultSet` as vulnerable.

I'm trying to figure out the reason behind this. Does it have something to do with Strings being immutable?

Though not the exact thing (due to confidentiality reasons), following is a sample code block that I'm concerned about:

```
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
 dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
 prepStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME, DOB FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=?");
 prepStmt.setInt(1, customerId);
 rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
 //do something

 while (rs.next()) {
  String name = rs.getString(1);
  Date dob = rs.getDate(2);
  //do something
 }
} catch (SQLException e) {
 //do something
} finally {
 if (rs != null) {
  try {
   rs.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   log.error("Database error. Could not close result set  - " + e.getMessage(), e);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Need more information. The linked OWASP article only indicates that you need to watch out for these methods.  Could also use some code to see what you're doing with it.

Comment: Added a sample code block. I'm just trying to understand why even OWASP lists only getString and getObject methods. Thanks

Comment: Show me where this code gets output on the page(s) in question. And show me the input. Looks vulnerable at first glance, but I need to see those two things.

Comment: It's not used directly for any output and the input can be even a hard-coded value. LAPSE+ still shows this as a Vulnerability Source.

Comment: What I meant was it's not used for a page output. For example, we can assume the retrieved Customer Name and DOB are finally added to a security token. By saying "Looks vulnerable at first glance", are you implying about stored XSS?

Comment: Yep, stored XSS. Other than that, if there IS a vulnerability, then I would presume it's with an obscure feature somewhere.

Comment: LAPSE+ is reporting this as an "Information Leakage". I'm trying to understand on what basis it reporting as such. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I haven't used LAPSE+, but any tool that reports something as vulnerable without telling or explaining why, is a piece of bantha poodoo.

Comment: It could be an information leakage vulnerability, if the argument to `getString()` was user-controlled. But since that part is static, I don't see where your tool derives the assessment from.

Comment: I believe it's reporting that simply because those two getters are listed in the mentioned OWASP list. Then the question is why OWASP lists only those two rather than all the resultset getters.

Comment: FWIW it's important to note that I would be very careful before using LAPSE+ for anything, the last release I can see is 2.8.1 from 2011 and the mailing list shows no activity since 2013

Comment: @RоryMcCune Thanks for the input. Even if consider LAPSE+ as obsolete, I would like to understand the reason for OWASP listing only those two getters. Unless, they are given only as examples, and all the getters should be considered as vulnerable sources, simply due to the reason they retrieve data.

Comment: Sounds bogus to me.  The only thing I can think of is that they want you to check to see if sensitive information is being returned from the database because garbage collection is handled by the JVM and a sensitive string may hide in memory for a while whereas if you use a char array you can write over it and clear it from memory.  In .NET you can use securestring for this kind of thing but I'm not sure of what your alternative here.  Also, this finding if valid is so low risk I wouldn't worry about it at all personally.

Comment: The OWASP page link in the question does not say that the items on that page are vulnerabilities. The page just lists all the ways that data enters into a Java app, which should be covered when reviewing an app code for vulnerabilities. There are no vulnerabilities per se in the code snippet in the question, but I personally avoid using positional references, e.g. getString(1) I prefer getString("NAME"). Also, I like to close preparedstatements.

Comment: Smells more like a "know what you're doing" than a real flaw (like OWASP page says). Object & String can have almost any value, while Date & Int can only be... dates & ints! Hence the "Look closer to these two".

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning might have been that ResultSet.getString and RestulSet.getObject should return a valid result no matter what the underlying value is for the column you specify. So if there was an SQLi attack and column 1 is usually a string but is now some secret number you'll get still a valid result and thus leak information about that result. Whereas ResultSet.getDate will throw an exception if it can't parse the column as a date so no information would be leaked, other than it's an invalid value.

Comment: maybe prepared statements are already great for reduction in SQL Injection. Error detection in software technology is a thing & so is error correction in a very minimal data exposure.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jcopenha's answer, perhaps you could try using getString( "column label" ). If the table format changes and the column indexes are offset, if you use the labels (select name as n) then referencing with getString( "n" ) should ensure that you get 'n' back. More to the point, if you use a label convention that differs from table column naming convention the two should never overlap.